# Android project with Custom ActionBar on Bottom of screen is floating up above the Keyboard

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

I'm working on a android project in xamarin and I've got a custom action bar that is on the bottom of the screen.  I use this between about three different screens but for some reason on a screen with a edittext and listview when the keyboard comes up the nav bar appears above the keyboard and it shouldn't.  Like the image below

Incorrect appearance :

[image]

When the keyboard comes up the navbar with the "?" image button shouldn't be there.

xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/LocationsRoot"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SearchView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#d3d3d3"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:text=" Select Location" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#d3d3d3"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/SearchText"
                    android:hint="Search"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/SearchLocationButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/GreenButton"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/search32x32" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/LocationsList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottomtoolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbarbottom"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this at your **OnCreate()** method:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustPan); // also,you can try this "SoftInput.AdjustNothing"
//other stuff and etc
       }
```

Soft keyboard will overlay your items.
Enjoy!

Comment: That fixed it thank you! I have to wait 22 hours to award the 50 points.

Comment: @HisnamewasRobertPaulson you're welcome!
It's ok :). So dunno who downvote your question,ill mark up your post ;).
Also you can do the same:)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `AndroidManifest`. 
In the `Activity` tag ,set `softinputType` to `AdjustPan`